# Can a C++ standard library header include a C standard header?

Tags: c++, c, std

I can only find in the standard draft N4582 that

> [res.on.headers/1] A C++ header may include other C++ headers.

It seems not to specify that whether a C++ header can include a C standard header.

If it is permitted, is it unsafe to use a global name defined in a C standard header even if this header is not included (since the program may implicitly include the header through some C++ standard header)?

Comment: I used to do this all the time (effectively mixing C and C++ code together) and it worked. Whether it's permitted according to the standard, i couldn't say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the purpose of the question you follow up with (name conflicts), yes, it certainly can. The reason is that the C++ standard library includes the `<c:::>` C++ headers for the C standard library contents, and the standard explicitly allows these to provide the names in the global namespace as well (in addition to mandatorily providing them in `::std`).

Further, based on Annex D [depr] of the C++ standard, the C standard library headers (the `<:::.h>` versions) are also part of the C++ standard library (albeit deprecated). This means [res.on.headers]/1 allows C++ headers to include them.

Answer (score 4):

Section [D.3 C standard library headers](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4582.pdf) of the C++ standard makes 26 C standard headers part of C++. Thus those are part of C++. Also many other C headers adhere to the shared subset of the languages (probably by `#ifdef`ing some things out) making them both, valid C and C++ headers.

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes late but adds something the others do not, so here goes....

Short answer: whether the standard allows a standard C++ header to include a standard C header remains unclear.

Other answers have correctly observed that the C++ standard

- allows a standard C++ header
- to include a standard C++ header.

What remains unclear is *whether a standard C header is a standard C++ header.* I can give evidence both ways.

**Why a C header is indeed a C++ header**

On GCC 6.24 with GNU's standard C library 2.24, the following test fails to compile.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    const int printf {42};
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << printf << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler complains, "reference to ‘printf’ is ambiguous," despite that the test lacks an explicit `#include <cstdio>`.

The judgment of the developers of a major compiler and standard library like GCC and GNU is hardly to be ignored.

Other answers have given further reasons I need not reprise here.

**Why a C header is not a C++ header**

The C++17 standard (draft [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)), footnote 166, reads:

> [T]he C++ headers for C library facilities may ... define names within the global namespace.

If C headers were C++ headers, then that would be an odd way to have written such a footnote, would it not? One would instead have expected the footnote to begin with words like, "The non-`<*.h>` C++ headers for C library facilities ..."

The last observation is inconclusive but, in [res.on.headers], the standard also reads:

> The C standard library headers shall include only their corresponding C++ standard library header....

Again, if C headers were C++ headers in the estimation of the person that wrote the words, then that would seem an odd way to have written them.

**Conclusion: ambiguous**

Unfortunately, like other answerers, I cannot find a clear answer in the standard one way or the other. Unlike other answerers, I would conclude that the answer remains ambiguous. Relevant sections in the standard include [contents], [res.on.headers] and [depr.c.headers].

**Opinion**

If you wish to know which alternative carries the preponderance of the evidence in my opinion, then I would tend to disagree with the other answers. For the reasons cited, I would tend to say that the standard did not allow a standard C++ header to include a standard C header. Such inclusion contradicts ordinary C++ usage, at any rate, insofar as such inclusion makes anonymous global namespaces harder to use. [Change `printf` to `foo` in my test and then ask what would happen if a future standard C library added a function `foo()`. Such an experiment illustrates the trouble.]

On the other hand, fighting one's toolchain is fairly pointless, isn't it? Until a future version of C++ clarifies, I for one mean to avoid anonymous global namespaces in source files that include standard library headers.

I suspect that, since the standard has deprecated the old styles by which standard C headers are used, the standards committee might not be thinking too hard about how to patch problems with the old style in the meantime. Maybe C++20 modules will afford a neat solution. We shall see.