# Are symbols from the C standard library reserved in C++?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, libc

This is a follow-up to a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68454294/3545273).

The original question had other problems but I had to realize that the main one (according to CLang) was a *redefinition of `time` as a different symbol* while only *nice* C++ includes were used.

So here is a stripped-down version:

```
#include<iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class time
{
public:
    int h, min, sec;
};

const int full = 60;

void canonify(time& pre)     // Error here (line 14)
{
    pre.min += pre.sec / full;
    pre.h += pre.min / full;
    pre.sec %= full;
    pre.min %= full;
}
int main()
{
    time a;                  // and here (line 23)
    a.h = 3;
    a.min = 128;
    a.sec = 70;
    canonify(a);
    cout << a.h << ":" << a.min << ":" << a.sec << endl;
}
```

Of course, replacing `time` with a different symbol or using `struct time` is enough to get rid of the problem. Said differently my question is **not** how to make the code run, but only whether we have to see symbols from the C library as *reserved tokens* in C++.
Clang 11 (on MSVC19) chokes with:

```
1>ess.cpp(14,15): error : must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'time' in this scope
1>...\ucrt\time.h(518,42): message : class 'time' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'time' here
1>ess.cpp(23,5): error : must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'time' in this scope
1>...\ucrt\time.h(518,42): message : class 'time' is hidden by a non-type declaration of 'time' here
```

So the question is: where does the C++ standard forbid freely using symbols from the C standard library when they are not explicitly included in a compilation unit?

---

Interestingly enough the same code (once translated...) works fine in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

//
typedef struct 
{
    int h, min, sec;
}time;
//
const int full = 60;
//
void canonify(time* pre)
{
    pre->min += pre->sec / full;
    pre->h += pre->min / full;
    pre->sec %= full;
    pre->min %= full;
}
int main()
{
    time a;
    a.h = 3;
    a.min = 128;
    a.sec = 70;
    canonify(&a);
    printf("%d:%d:%d\n", a.h, a.min, a.sec);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589226/can-a-c-standard-library-header-include-a-c-standard-header  This seems like a dupe to me, but I am not confident to use my dupe hammer.

Comment: The global namespace is very polluted with identifiers.  Titus Winters called it the wild west.  Your code is not forbidden from using symbols in the global namespace from the C standard library.  Including the C++ wrapped C header files are not obligated to provide the C symbols in the global namespace (but most of them do — most, but not all), regardless they are *reserved*.

Comment: @bolov: It is indeed the same problem. But the language-lawyer tag ask answers with precise reference to the standard. But I must admit that I had found the other question first I would not have asked this one ;-)

Comment: FYI, `std::endl` is totally redundant here.  Returning from `main` will flush `std::cout`.  And in general there's usually no need to force-flush as part of printing a `'\n'` - cout is usually already line-buffered in cases where that's useful (i.e. when stdout is a TTY).

Comment: The reason your translation to C works, is that the C standard _forbids_ C standard-library headers to (behave as-if they) include each other (with a small and documented set of exceptions), whereas the C++ standard _allows_ C++ standard library headers to include each other.  So `iostream` can, and does, expose symbols from `ctime`, but `stdio.h`, _when compiled as C_, may _not_ expose symbols from `time.h`.

Comment: @bolov: Rightly so - neither question is tagged with a C++ Standard, and this is the sort of question which requires a precise Standard reference. In particular, the proposed dupe would be based on C++14, while we now have C++20

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> **[extern.names]**
>
> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/extern.names#3) Each name from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with extern "C" linkage, both in namespace std and in the global namespace.

Note that this paragraph reserves the name itself. So aliasing `time` in the global namespace violates this contract.

Comment: The solution being to wrap your own `time` inside your own `namespace`.

Comment: @Eljay - Under the caveat you may not use C language linkage for it.

Comment: @Eljay Which is what one should always do for every declaration (except for that one namespace and things like `main`.  And I suppose cross language interfaces.)

Comment: Thank you, I could not find that reference. But the number of symbols in C standard library is *laaaarge*, and I would expect many programmers to not know them all...

Comment: @SergeBallesta And if you depend on third party C libraries (or lazy C++ libraries), then the number of symbols is even larger. This is part of why one should always avoid using the global namespace.

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Cautious use of namespaces avoids the problem, as was mentioned already. At least you have recourse in C++. [C pretty much does the same](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3), but relies on convention rather than a language mechanism to avoid collisions.

Comment: @M.M - They do https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.link#2 . Unless you don't count them as types?

Answer (score 18):

> Where does the C++ standard forbids to use freely symbols from the C standard library

Latest draft:

> [extern.names]
>
> Each name from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a name with extern "C" linkage, both in namespace std and in the global namespace.
>
> Each function signature from the C standard library declared with external linkage is reserved to the implementation for use as a function signature with both extern "C" and extern "C++" linkage, or as a name of namespace scope in the global namespace.

---

> when they are not explicitely included in a compilation unit?

If you use the standard library at all, then all name reservations of the standard library are in effect.

If you include any standard header (or, any header whose exact content you don't control and thus may include standard headers), then you may be indirectly including other standard headers, including those inherited from C.